# instance variables added in rails helpers are not available in views (templates)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I am trying to add some instance variables in helpers like the following:

```
module ApplicationHelper
 def title=(title)
   @title = title
 end

 def title
  @title
 end
end
```

and when I assign title in views/pages/index.html.erb like the following:

```
<% title = 'Listing Pages' %>
```

and try to show it in the views/layouts/application.html.erb like the following:

```
<%= title %>
```

it is showing as '' and after some debugging, looks like @title is not being set.

**Why are the instance variables added in the helpers not available in the views (templates)?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, you can implement the getter and setter in one line by using attr_accessor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that Ruby thinks that what you are doing in

```
title = 'Listing Pages'
```

is as assignment to a local variable `title`.

Try to prefix it with `self` and see if it helps:

```
self.title = 'Listing Pages'
```

Comment: @Milan:
thanks a lot, it did solve the problem. Is there any other way to let ruby understand that what we are trying to do is trying to call method instead of appending prepending?

Comment: I don't think there's any better way. That's the way the interpreter works. The best way to avoid this kind of problem is just to watch this "a = b" pattern and have a little thought about it. The rule of thumb is: when assigning through a setter method within an instance always prepend it with self.

Comment: One possible workaround: Name your setter method something like set_title instead of title=. Then you won't need to add self and just use it like this: set_tile "Listing pages"